# Serializes ManyToMany relations in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to serializing ManyToMany fields. So, in the response for tje Application model should also the band and the band description listed. But I've got the following error message:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bands` on
> serializer `OsdSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
> incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Application`
> instance. Original exception text was: 'Application' object has no
> attribute 'bands'.

Anyone who knows why it doesnt work?

**models.py**

```
class Band(models.Model):
    """Database models for satellit's bands information"""

    band = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    in_satellite = models.ForeignKey('Satellite', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    wavelength = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default='0', help_text='Central wavelength (nm)')
    resolution = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0, default='0', help_text='Spatial resolution (m)')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.in_satellite, self.band)


class Satellite(models.Model):
    """Database models for satellite information"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    accr = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='European Space Agency')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Indice(models.Model):
    """Database models for index information"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    accr = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    satellite_to_use = models.ForeignKey('Satellite', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    needed_bands = models.ManyToManyField(Band)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Application(models.Model):
    """Database models for application information"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    indice_to_use = models.ForeignKey('Indice', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Band
        fields = ['band', 'description', ]

class OsdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bands = BandSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'bands',]
```

**views.py**

```
class OsdView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        applications = Application.objects.all()
        serializer = OsdSerializer(applications, many=True)
        return Response({"Your open space data:": serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need to change the `OsdSerializer` to specify the relation you want to include in the serialized data:

```
bands = BandSerializer(source='indice_to_use.needed_bands', many=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but here i don't see any relation between two of your models Band and Application.

I think you might need to find some relation between Band model and Application model only then and then you will get the band object in output associated with corresponding application object.

Comment: I've added all models to my answer to make it clearer. The relationship is not directly between the Application and Band models.

Application model has a relationship with the Indice model and the Indice model has a relationship with the Band model. 

I want to have the Bands that a relate to the Indice that is related to the Application.  Y'know? :D

Comment: ok, so for that you have to change bands field in `OsdSerializer` to set the relation you want get in data.

`bands = BandSerializer(source='indice_to_use.needed_bands', many=True)`